# Realm with swift, getting error "Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Im getting this error when setting a list equal to another list. Here is the code:

**Function where i am getting the error:**

```
func loadContactInfo() {
        
    selectedInfo = selectedContact?.info
        
}
```

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class InfoViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    var selectedInfo : Results<ContactInfo>?
    var selectedContact: Contact?
```

**Contact** is a realm class that holds a list of **ContactInfo**, which is another realm class with more properties.

Here is the contact class and ContactInfo class:

```
class Contact : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    let info = List<ContactInfo>()
}
```

```
class ContactInfo : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var phone : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var birthday : String = ""
    var parentContact = LinkingObjects(fromType: Contact.self, property: "info")
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Contact` class?

Comment: So you are trying to assign  `ContactInfo` to a property of type `Result<ContactInfo>`?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make it on-topic.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson im trying to set selected info to a newly created Result<ContactInfo>